# GridView not updating when data comes from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a **GridView** control that gets data from two tables, the first one contains a primary key, a name (string) and a foreign key to the second table, The second table contains a primary key "referenced by the foreign key mentioned" and a name (string), i was able to display the id, name (first table) and the name (second table) using an inner join but i can't update the data in the tables using the GridView (when pressing update nothing happens at all, or no change occurs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother i found a solution to the problem on Microsoft website, i am sorry i didn't make my question pretty clear and here is a link to what i was looking for: [Editing with Template Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.edititemtemplate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand of your question what you have is a situation that you must a apply a nested gridview.

A gridview shows the content of a table (datatable or a collection).
If you want to show other collection that is inside each row of your primary gridview, you will need
to build a second Gridview or listview or repeater to show that information.

with the primary griview you can use the OnItemDataBound to assign the datasource of the nested gridview or what you choose to show that information based in primary key of the row.

Comment: NO, i was able to bring columns from the two different tables into the same GridView (it worked very well), but when i want to update the data (the update includes one of the tables only), i can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after clicking Update you need to call your read method again  to refresh your gridview.

something Like:

```
  UpdateMethod()
  {

  //YOUR UPDATE STUFF


  //REBIND DATA WITH UPDATED RECORDS
  RefreshMethod(); //YOUR BINDING METHOD TO DATAGRID STUFF


 }
```